# -30V/+30V protection

Tags: mosfet, protection, fuses

I'm looking for a symmetric +30/0 -30/0 V protection (overvoltage (+-35 V), undervoltage (+-10 V), overcurrent (4.5 mA) and reverse polarity) for an opamp. I would like a circuit that reactivates himself after some time or when the fault is removed. So, if possible, no fuse.
At first the eFuse seemed perfect but out of stock until a least July...
For the postive part, I figured an LM317 as current limiter and the LTC4365 will do the trick.

[image]

And it works! [image]

But LTC4365 doesn't work in the negative part. So if you had any suggestion :)

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: couldn't I use a "inverting switching regulator" connected to the Vout of the first mos regulator ? SOmething like the LT3757 (but with the right specs)

Comment: PTC fuse with a diode for reverse... I can't believe they are out of stock, they are literally thousands of types you can choose from.

Comment: What peak value of over-voltage can exist? How much current could be associated with the energy from an over-voltage (or what impedance is the source).

Comment: @Andy aka I don't know. They idea is to make an "idiot protection". To avoid that someone plugs in the wrong source.

Comment: What if they plug-in mains AC voltage at 250 volt RMS. Would you expect the circuit to self-protect against that event?

Comment: @Andy If possible, that would be great.

Comment: But, what if they plug the circuit onto a three phase supply of 415 volts ? Can you predict where this is [leading you](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/e0/f5/18e0f5165896297b552c86989ecf6381.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

"So, if possible, no fuse"

Fuses protect from over current faults.

For your over voltage protection I suggest you to use bidirectional TVS diodes.

Bidirectional TVS diodes are always symmetric. Example +/- 30 V or +/- 24V

They protect your circuitry from temporary over voltage faults.

I've using for years NXP's PESD1CAN devices.

Try this selection at Digikey.com

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/tvs-diodes/144?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWAJngFZ4A2EAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfImACcsWUhCpImXIRLkQABlYdukPoNETJ0kNS2cAbjgAEAEyHEHeHK0lA

Comment: I know fuse are meant to do that. But currrent limiter work fine too for my application.

Comment: You can use both. TVS comes first, than the fuse. Why that? Because fuses can't stand voltage peaks of +/- 4kV.

Comment: fuses are holy and in most places mandatory by law. However this is not quite the case. I agree with TVS and fuses in pair. PPTCs are good too: a cheap polarity protection is a sturdy diode which shorts the supply when polarity is reversed and a PPTC that opens to avoid said diode to go aflame. Advantage: no Vf loss on the supply